# "Fuzzy" hashtables in Python to replace elif chains?

Tags: python-3.x, hashmap, simplify

The Pythonic way to choose one of many execution paths or bits of data dependent on a variable is to use a hashtable, like so:

```
mapping = {'bar':"xyzzy", 'foo':"plugh", 'baz':"frobnitz"}
magic = mapping[command]
```

What do I do in the case where I want to choose an execution path based on whether or not a value is within one of many ranges of values?

Or, to put it more succinctly, how do I pythonicize this:

```
    #A value from one to four indicates an O-type star. 4/58 chance.
    if typeselec <= 4:
        self.specttype="O"
    #A value from 5-20 indicates a B-type star. 15/58 chance.
    elif typeselec <= 20:
        self.specttype="B"
    #A value from 20-30 indicates an A-type star. 10/58 chance.
    elif typeselec <= 30:
        self.specttype="A"
    #A value from 31-36 indicates an F-type star. 6/58 chance.
    elif typeselec <= 36:
        self.specttype="F"
    #A value from 37-40 indicates a G-type star. 4/58 chance.
    elif typeselec <= 40:
        self.specttype="G"
    #A value from 41-50 indicates a K-type star. 10/58 chance.
    elif typeselec <= 22:
        self.specttype="K"
    #A value from 50-58 indicates an M-type star. 8/58 chance.
    else:
        self.specttype="M"
```

One obvious means would be `{1:'O', 2:'O',3:'O',4:'O',5:'B',6:'B'...}`, but that seems awfully inelegant and inefficient. Is there any other way?

Comment: You could build your own `FuzzyMap` with the logic you want in `__getitem__`

Comment: I could, and that would *look* nice, but in the end it'd still be an elif chain, albiet a hidden elif chain. I'm wondering if I can preserve the O(1) performance of Python's non-fuzzy maps.

Comment: The `O(1)` comes from use of hashes, so the only other option would be a custom key object where all the values in each range hash to the same value.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured as well, and I doubt that'd be possible. But I've been wrong before.

Comment: could you elaborate on why you found inelegant to cache the value of computation in an hash ? by the way, if you values are contiguous, you could consider using a list though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly this kind or problem is used as example for the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/bisect.html#other-examples) module.

Adapted to your problem it would look like this:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def select_type(typeselec,
                breakpoints=[4, 20, 30, 36, 40, 50],
                types='0BAFGKM'):
    return types[bisect_left(breakpoints, typeselec)]


for i in range(59):
    print(i, select_type(i))
```

The difference to the example from the doc is that here the breakpoint is part of the lower bound (`<=`), where as in the example it's part of the upper (`>=`), so `bisect_left` needs to be used instead of `bisect` (which is an alias for `bisect_right`).

Altough `bisect` doesn't have a time complexity of `O(1)`, it used binary search, so it has a time complexity of `O(log(n))`, which for larger `n` would be a good improvement of the `O(n)` of the `if` cascade.

Answer (score 2):

Store your `specttype`s in a weighted list and look them up with `typeselec` as index.  After generating the list, lookup is O(1).

```
letters = 'OBAFGKM'
frequencies = (4, 15, 10, 6, 4, 10, 8)

specttypes = []
for i in range(len(letters)):
    l = letters[i]
    f = frequencies[i]
    specttypes = specttypes + [l] * f

self.specttype = specttypes[typeselec-1] # Subtract 1 because of zero indexing.
```

You could use a dictionary instead of the separate iterables `letters` and `frequencies`, but the resultant `specttypes` would be ordered alphabetically unless you used an [ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Note that `specttypes` has 57 elements as defined above, not the 58 you mentioned.  That's because your last code comment contradicts itself; I assigned 'M' a frequency of 8 instead of 9 (*i.e.*, indices 50-57 instead of 50-58).

Comment: I like the efficiency of this, but I'm gonna have to go with the `bisect` answer for greater elegance.

Answer (score 0):

If we had a large set of ranges I'd store the numbers in a sorted sequence and use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to do a binary search; it's O(log(n)) for lookups rather than O(n). Still not the O(1) of perfect hashing. Of course, with the very limited set you've shown you might as well store the values in a single string and use it as a plain lookup table. chikinn's example does this but with a list (which, come to think of it, will be more efficient - no need to look up the string version of characters).